# one to many query with where Has returns unwanted results

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query and don't find the correct solution for this:

```
    $orders = Shipping::with('orderitems')
        ->whereHas('orderitems',  function($query)  {
            $query->where('status','=',NULL);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

I'm querying a one to many relationship

```
public function orderitems() {
    return $this->hasMany('OrderItems');
}
```

Above query returns the correct resultset when all entries within 'orderItems' fit the condition, having status 'NULL'. The problem is, when I have an order with 2 items and one of the two items doesn't have status 'NULL', both items are returned though I only want the item which actually has status 'NULL' being returned.

I've tried it with a whereNested query and a query scope, but I think this is not the solution to the problem. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` will actually filter `Shipping` based on if they have at least one `orderitem` that matches the condition. I'm pretty sure what you want is use `with` with a condition:

```
$orders = Shipping::with(['orderitems' => function($query){
    $query->where('status','=',NULL);
}])->paginate(10);
```

#### Edit

Add a `whereHas` if you also want only order with at least one item with status `NULL`:

```
$orders = Shipping::with(['orderitems' => function($query){
    $query->where('status','=',NULL);
}])->whereHas('orderitems',  function($query){
    $query->where('status','=',NULL);
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: That's the right direction, thank you! Problem now is if I give a status to the items, I get an undefined variable error on the next page reload, so I will need to get rid of the orders in the query, but that should be easy with another whereHas.

Comment: hehe, exactly what I did! Perfect, thank you very much!